# Некорректное заполнение JSON файла

Tags: java, android, json

Заполняю JSON файл строками. Сначала заполняю JSONObject, потом помещаю его в JSONArray. В итоге получаю: `[{"number":"4","count":"2","price":"290","name":"Печенье «Вкусное»"},{"number":"4","count":"2","price":"290","name":"Печенье «Вкусное»"},{"number":"4","count":"2","price":"290","name":"Печенье «Вкусное»"},{"number":"4","count":"2","price":"290","name":"Печенье «Вкусное»"},{"number":"4","count":"2","price":"290","name":"Печенье «Вкусное»"}].`
Когда строки повторяться не должны. Аргументы проверял через Toast прямо в цикле, все разные.

```
Bundle arguments = getIntent().getExtras();
int size = (int) arguments.get("size");
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray();

for(int i = 0; i<size; i++) {
    String count = arguments.get("count" + i).toString();
    String price = arguments.get("price" + i).toString();
    String name = arguments.get("name" + i).toString();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("number", String.valueOf(i));
        jsonObject.put("count", count);
        jsonObject.put("price" ,price);
        jsonObject.put("name" ,name);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    arr.put(jsonObject);
}
```

Подскажите, как правильно заполнить JSON ?

Comment: Перенесите строку `JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();` в тело цикла, первой строкой

Comment: Это помогло, спасибо! @ЮрийСПб